# Finish Facebook Activity

Tags: android, facebook

I my application, I will start Facebook activity.

How to make it return to my application when the user pressed back button?

Current it will just stay in Facebook (went back to other pages in Facebook) instead of going back to my application when the back button was pressed.

Comment: What version of the Facebook app are you using?

Comment: It doesn't matter, apk 10.0 ~ apk 25.0, are the same.

Comment: Which Facebook activity are you starting, and how are you starting it?